# Meaning of field: Number of buffer pool pages for an index performing explain analysis

Tags: indexing, db2

I am analysing the access plan of a SQL statement in IBM Data Studio using the explain tool.
I have added a new index which drasticllay improves the costs my SQL statement. I am interesting in the B-Tree structure of the index. The number of index levels is three. I would like to know how many level 2 pages resides in memory and the branching factor (fan out, e. g. 1001) of a level 2 node. Thus, I tried to have a look at the field: Number of buffer pool pages. It is 191646. The table which is referenced by the index has also 191646 for the Number of buffer pool pages. Obviously both numbers are identical. Moreover the Number of index leaf pages is 35257. It makes no sence that there are 191646 buffer pool pages if there are 35257 index leaf pages.

How can I estimate the size of the complete B-Tree? How can I find out how many index pages exist (at each level) and how many of them reside in memory?